# Abstract Algebra Proof Help

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group. Prove that each element of $G$ appears exactly once in each column and exactly once in each row of the multiplication table for $G$.

Proof:
Suppose some $a \in G$ appears twice in some column of the multiplication table. Then for some $b \in G$, the equation $xb = a$ has at least two solutions, say $c$ and $d$. So $cb = a = db$. Since there is some $f \in G$ such that $bf = e$, then $c = ce = cbf = dbf = de = d$. Thus this is a contradiction.

Suppose some $a \in G$ appears twice in some row of the multiplication table. Then some $b \in G$ where $bx = a$ has at least two solutions, $c$ and $d$. So $bc = a = bd$. Then there is an $f \in G$ such that $fb = e$, so $c = ec = fbc = fbd = ed = d$. Thus this is a contradiction.

Comment: it seems correct

Answer (score 1):

You've shown that an element of $G$ doesn't appear more than once in a row/column of the multiplication table. What's still left is to show that it appears as least once.

If $G$ is finite, this follows from a counting argument, but the general case is easy enough.

In general, the row for (left-)multiplication by $b$ has the element $a$ in the column for (right-)multiplication by $b^{-1}a$.